# VSCode async setStatusBarMessage

Tags: node.js, promise, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In context of extension for MS VSCode.

There is a method in `vscode` module:

```
export function setStatusBarMessage(text: string): Disposable;
```

Looks like it works on promises inside, because this code:

```
function test()
{
    vscode.window.setStatusBarMessage("computing...");
    compute().then(x => console.log(x));
}

function compute(): Promise<string>
{
    let res = "";
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        for (let i = 1; i < 999999; i++)
            for (let j = 1; j < 9999999; i++)
                res += (i++) * (j++);
        resolve(res); 
    });
}

test();
```

shows status message after computing resolved.

How can I wait for StatusBarMessage being redrawn?

Comment: Asynchronous functions don't necessarily use promises. setStatusBarMessage doesn't expose any promise to chain. It triggers some GUI redraw mechanism that may work asynchronously (you would expect that because that's more  efficient). Did you try to apply random delay and check how it works? E.g. with requestAnimationFrame, or setTimeout 0, or more for `compute().then(x => console.log(x))`?

Comment: Yes, timeout = 100 solves this, but this way is rather ugly

Comment: Since it doesn't provide a way to notify on completion, it's likely the only way. Consider opening an issue.